# how to put text over image without absolute positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for layout, one of the difficulties I have run into is about how to put the text over image. I have tried all things I can do such as using background-image which does not work. One of the approaches is to place image as relative and put the text in the absolute position.

However for my issue, I can't use absolute position because I have so many images and texts' lengths are varied. So I have to solve issue this by using align-center..

If someone is familiar with this issue, could you give some advice for this problem.. I have to put the text over the image on the very center vertically and horizontally.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <img src="img/1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <img src="img/2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <img src="img/3.jpg">
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: *"because I have so many images and texts' lengths are varied"*, you can use relative length for centering your texts.

Comment: It's not possible without absolute and relative. Suggestion: add unique classes near col-sm-auto and use it as relative. Then make the text inside the node absolute.

Comment: If the image source isnt changing, then you can try setting `background: url(img/1.jpg)` from CSS and adjust its position using `background-position`.

Comment: @IshantSolanki What about the text?

Comment: Do you know why background-image or background is impossible? .x {
  background: url("img/1.jpg");
}, it never works.

Answer (score 0):

If the image source isnt changing, then you can try setting background: url(img/1.jpg) from CSS and adjust its position using background-position

Check out the fiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/yktvod54/2/

html

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-sm-auto image-1">
  text1
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-auto image-2">
  text2
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-auto image-3">
  text3 with longer text
  </div>
```

css

```
.col-sm-auto {

  color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-sm-auto.image-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: 
  url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/8/89/Cute-Cat.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130828113117");
  background-size: cover;
}

.col-sm-auto.image-2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/8/89/Cute-Cat.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130828113117");
    background-size: cover;
}

.col-sm-auto.image-3 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: 
    url("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/8/89/Cute-Cat.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130828113117");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: The image is different for each div. But yours are all same.

Comment: this is a good solution for static HTML page when the page becomes dynamic then there will be problems.

Comment: Depends on how dynamic the page becomes. If the url starts coming from the server instead of knowing it from the start, then this solution will not work. However that is a different problem altogether. The questioner mentions the url in the html so its safe to assume we know from the start the list of images with their URLs. We can have these URLs bound to each css classnames. And dynamically inject the class into wherever we want the image to be displayed.

Comment: I did not think about using flex display, it seems good idea, I will try it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome! Would love to know if the solution actually worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as a background to a div, make that div `display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` and give it a width/height. The flex alignments will push everything to the center of the div, but it needs a height/width or the div will only be the size of the text. Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` and the text will wrap around, but there isnt a nice breakpoint like with `word-break`

Answer (score -1):

> I can't use absolute position because I have so many images and texts' lengths are varied

You can use relative lengths for positioning you texts so they will be centered whatever their size.
You will need the [translate CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) as well.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image-wrapper figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<figure class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/n5wsKU/bg3.jpg" alt="A nice pic!">
  <figcaption>A text that fits on one line</figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

In case you still don't want to use absolute positioning, here is another solution using a **background-image** instead of an **img** tag:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.image-wrapper.image-01 {
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/n5wsKU/bg3.jpg') center center / cover;
}

.image-wrapper p {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper image-01">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Questioner wanted "without absolute positioning"

Comment: The solution by Quentin successfully solved my issue, one thing I have to solve now is even though the text can fit into one line, but it goes over to next line. Of course short text is written in one line however the text get a little long, it goes to next line. so I put padding-left and padding-right to 0px, it still goes over two lines. If you have some solutions, please give me advice?

Comment: Just add **width:100%** and **text-align:center** to the text tag! It should work. I'll edit my answer with a longer text.